# Calculate the integrals $\int_0^a \frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^2} \mathrm dx$ and $\int_0^a \frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^3} \mathrm dx $

Tags: calculus

Given that $$\int_0^a \frac{1}{x^2+a^2} \mathrm dx = \frac{\pi}{4a}$$ calculate the integrals $$\int_0^a \frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^2} \mathrm dx$$ and $$\int_0^a \frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^3} \mathrm dx $$ .

I tried setting $$I(t)=\int_0^a \frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^t} \mathrm dx$$ and computing $$I'(t)$$ and then integrating but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried setting $$I(t)=\int_0^a \frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^t} \mathrm dx$$ and computing $$I'(t)$$ and then integrating but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: Editing the post to add your attempt will prevent closure, or induce reopen vote after closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use the derivative under the integral sign (also known as the Feynman trick), taking into consideration the Leibniz integral rule https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Establish

$$ I(a) = \int_{0}^{a}\frac{1}{x^{2} + a^{2}}dx = \frac{\pi}{4a}  $$

And perform the derivative of $I(a)$ with respect to $a$:

$$\frac{\partial I(a)}{\partial a} = \int_{0}^{a}\frac{1}{(x^{2} + a^{2})^{2}}(-2a)dx + \frac{1}{2a^{2}} = -\frac{\pi}{4a^{2}}$$

Using Leibniz rule as commented, so the final result is:

$$ \int_{0}^{a}\frac{1}{(x^{2} + a^{2})^{2}}dx = \frac{2 + \pi}{8a^{3}}$$

And the same philosophy with the next integral, using this as help.

Answer (score 2):

Integrating by parts you can deduce a recursive formula:
$$\int\frac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)^n} = \frac{x}{(x^2+a^2)^n} + 2n\int\frac{x^2}{(x^2+a^2)^{n+1}}\,dx = \frac{x}{(x^2+a^2)^n} + 2n\int\frac{x^2+a^2-a^2}{(x^2+a^2)^{n+1}}\,dx = \cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

Set $x=a\tan u$, then $dx = a \sec^2 u du$, using these two your indefinite form of the two integrations become (i) $\int \frac{\cos^2 u}{a^3} du$ and (ii) $\int \frac{\cos^4 u}{a^5} du$. I hope you can go from here.